# Periodic boundary condition confusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, periodic-functions

If we have a differential equation on [a, b], I know that a periodic boundary condition is written like $$f(a)=f(b)$$ in my book.

I am confused why I am being told in classes that $$f(a)=f(b)=0$$ is NOT a periodic boundary condition. I was hoping someone could enlighten me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: The issue is, there definitely are periodic boundaries that satisfy $f(a)=f(b)=0$, but not all do. For example, take $f(x)=\sin(x)+10$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have the zero boundary conditions:

$$f(a)=f(b)=0$$

We are restricting ourselves only to the functions that are zero at those two points.

On the other hand, for the periodic boundary conditions, we have:

$$f(a)=f(b)=C$$

Where $C$ is some arbitrary (and usually unspecified) value. We could definitely set $C=0$, however calling this case periodic would be confusing.

The same way calling the function $y(x)= a$ a linear function would be confusing, just because we can set $b=0$ in the expression for the linear function $y(x)= a+bx$.

---

Usually, one calls the b.c. periodic when we can't say what value $C$ takes. We only know that $f(a)=f(b)$, that's it. In other words, we know less information about the function than in the case of zero boundary conditions.